# How to rewrite directory from root to sub directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite my sub directory to root:

forexample http://example.com/demo to http://example.com/img/demo
here is my currunt htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /img/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

this works fine but it is changing url in browser,
when I go to 
http://example.com/demo
it redirects to http://example.com/img/demo/ and url changes in browser, 
How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **turn off** the directory slash

To fix this, Add the following line above RewriteEngine directive

```
DirectorySlash Off
```